# How to force invoke method with object type input value without any type casting in a series of overloaded methods?

Tags: oop, overloading

For example I'm having a class with three overloaded methods like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    int sum(int i)
    {
       // Method implementation.
    }
    int sum(string x)
    {
       // Method implementation.
    }
    int sum(object o)
    {
       // Method implementation.
    }
}
```

My question is when I call the sum method of MyClass by passing any value (integer, string or object) it should invoke only third method (with object type input parameter)

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyClass obj = new MyClass();
      obj.sum(10);
      obj.sum("X")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have specific overloads for other types if you always want to call the version that takes an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "without type casting" but you can't, because you need some way to indicate to the compiler which version to call, and the runtime uses the type it sees to do that bit. Boxing the int as an object means the compiler will pick the object version

```
sum(1);//call int version
sum((object)1); //call object version
sum((string)(object)"1"); //call string version
sum((object)(int)(object)1); //call object version
```

Comment: I believe it's the compiler and not the runtime that makes this decision.

Comment: @Caius Jard .. I totally agree with you. Actually the same question was asked to me during an interview and I explained the same thing to interviewer ... but he said there is way to achieve this. .. when I asked him to explain .. he replied post it online .. you will get multiple answers ... might be he is extra ordinary genius ... but I could not find any better answer.

Comment: I posted it here .. hoping that someone might have the answer which interviewer was looking for :P

Comment: Perhaps you can subclass it with only an object version that is declared with the new keyword, and this will replace all the parent definitions- not sure-never done it/can't see why you'd need to/can't test cos I'm posting from an iphone

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that if you sometimes want to call one version of the `sum` function when working with `int`s and sometimes want to call another, overloading probably isn't the right tool to use. Overloading works best when you are implementing conceptually the same operation for a number of different types, and you want the compiler to figure out automatically which function is the right one to call for each type; if you need more manual control over which function is called, you're probably better off using different names.

That said, if you're sure that this is what you want to do, you could implement the overloaded version for object in terms of another function in the public interface, as in:

```
class MyClass
{
    int sum(int i)
    {
         // Method implementation.
    }
    int sum(string x)
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }
    int sum(object o)
    {
        sum_object(o);
    }
    int sum_object(object o)
    {
        // Method implementation for objects
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to apply the object version to `int` and `string` objects, you just call `sum_object` directly instead.

Comment: that is not overloading .. you are creating a totally different method.

Comment: There's still an overloaded version of `sum` for objects - I'm just providing an alternate way of calling the function that you actually want to call when overload resolution would select the "wrong" version of `sum` for your purposes.